# How to execute a dymola model from java?

Tags: java, dymola

We have a dymola model and we want to execute it on a linux server from java with the possibility to change the values of some of the parameters .

We have been looking at using the [javaFMI library](https://bitbucket.org/siani/javafmi/wiki/Home) to execute the model from an FMU file, but dymola seems to only generates binaries for windows. Is there a way to generate an FMU executable in linux from a dymola model (i.e. with linux binaries)?

Any other suggestion on how to reach this goal is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Linux version of Dymola to get a FMU that runs on Linux.

The Dymola User Manual Volume 2 has some short notes about requirements and limitations of FMU export on Linux in chapter 6.10.2 *Exporting FMUs from Dymola*

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to get an FMU with Linux binaries from Dymola. To the best of my understanding the FMUs generated by the Linux version of Dymola also only generates windows binaries, so we moved the project to Windows.

Comment: I tried with Dymola 2018 FD01 on openSUSE 42.3: It creates linux FMUs. The exported FMU has 32 and 64 bit .so-files in the binaries folder. Just open the fmu like a zip file and check its content.

Comment: Good to know. It wasn't so clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Dymola User Manual Volume 2 chapter 6.6?

Find the Manual in Help -> Documentation (or by hitting the F1 button in Dymola).